# Order of steps in Kosaraju's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, computer-science, kosaraju-sharir

The [Wikipedia summary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm) of the Kosaraju-Sharir algorithm is as follows:

> Let G be a directed graph and S be an empty stack.
>
> - While S does not contain all vertices.
>
>   - Choose an arbitrary vertex v not in S.
>   - Perform a depth-first search starting at v. Each time that depth-first search finishes expanding a vertex u, push u onto S.
> - Reverse the directions of all arcs to obtain the transpose graph.
> - While S is nonempty:
>
>   - Pop the top vertex v from S.
>   - Perform a depth-first search starting at v in the transpose graph.
>   - The set of visited vertices will give the strongly connected component containing v; record this and remove all these vertices from the graph G and the stack S. Equivalently, breadth-first search (BFS) can be used instead of depth-first search.

But in my textbook - Sedgewick's [Algorithms (fourth edition)](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/42directed/) - it describes the steps of the algorithm as follows:

> - Given a digraph G, compute the reverse post-order of its reverse digraph. G<sup>R</sup>
> - Run a standard DFS on G, but consider the unmarked vertices in the order just computed instead of the standard numerial order
> - The set of all vertices...

The conclusion drawn in the final step is identical, as are the operations performed in those preceding it - but it seems that those operations are given in different orders: Wikipedia tells me to start by doing a DFS on G and *then* transposing it, doing the second DFS on G<sup>R</sup>, whereas my textbook suggests that I begin with the transpose, do the first DFS on G<sup>R</sup> and the second on G.

**My primary question** is: Am I understanding this correctly, or am I misinterpreting what one or the other is saying?

**Secondly:** Intuitively, it seems as though these operations are transitive and therefore that these two "different methods" are in fact equivalent, and will always yield the same final result. I've tested this intuition on a couple of digraphs and it seems to hold true - but is it?

**Thirdly:** Assuming it is, is there any objective reason to prefer one over the other, or is it simply a matter of preference?

Comment: Cross-posted on CS.SE: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/26259/755. [Cross-posting on multiple SE sites violates site rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/160917).  Please don't do that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is cross posted: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/26259/755

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO the two algorithms are equivalent but there is a slight difference. The difference is in the order of SCCs (strongly connected components) output from them.

Say we have an acyclic di-graph having SCCs as S1, S2, S3, S4 in that order.

```
S1 -> S2 -> S3 -> S4
```

**Algorithm 1 (Wikipedia).**

When you build the stack S, for any vertex v, all the vertices coming after v shall enter the stack S before v, because we are carrying out DFS on the forward graph.

Now we reverse the graph:

```
R_S1 <- R_S2 <- R_S3 <- R_S4
```

The first vertex to be popped from Stack `S` shall be in `R_S1`. Hence when you perform the DFS, the first SCC to be output shall be `R_S1`.

**Algorithm 2 (book).**

Here we first reverse the graph:

```
R_S1 <- R_S2 <- R_S3 <- R_S4
```

Now when we conduct the DFS on any vertex `v`, the vertices coming before `v` (in original graph) shall be **ordered** before v. Also, since we start the order_index from `N` and then decrement the order_index, all the vertices coming after `v` shall have a lower topological ordering than v.

Original graph:

```
S1 -> S2 -> S3 -> S4
```

The lowest ordered vertex shall now be in `S4`. Hence the first SCC that will be output from the graph shall be `S4` as opposed to `R_S1` in the first case.

Comment: Both algorithms are correct as explained above. The only reason algorithm 2 may be preferred over algorithm 1 is that it does not require extra space, whereas algorithm 1 requires O(N) extra space in the form of Stack.

Comment: The second algorithm also requires O(V) space in the form of the stack, to store reverse post-order sequence of vertices. Hence both the algorithms are equivalent in terms of performance and implementation. To the main idea is the same in both, which is in a digraph, strongly connected components are the same in original and reverse graph.